# % in built-in file name function of GNU make

Tags: makefile, gnu

I encountered some code in a makefile like following. Could anyone teach me what does % in following code means.

```
 $(addsuffix .o, % $(objects))
```

I searched GNU Make reference and found

```
$(addsuffix pattern, names...)
```

But what does a % mark in this function means.

```
$(addsuffix .o, % $(objects))
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just try it and see what it does?  In the argument to the `addsuffix` function, `%` means `%`.  It's not special in any way, it's just the literal percent character.  So the output of this:

```
objects = foo bar biz baz
$(info $(addsuffix .o, % $(objects))
```

will be:

```
%.o foo.o bar.o biz.o baz.o
```

Comment: Thanks!!! You gave me an very important hint.
The % here will be extended to '%.o', which accept any file end of .o

Comment: If this construct is being used in a target context, be aware that it's not portable: newer versions of GNU make do not allow patterns and explicit targets to appear in the same rule.